# Linq : Load parent and child entities

Tags: .net, vb.net, linq, entity-framework, .net-4.5

I am attempting to load data from my SQL Server 2008 database into a server side DTO to transfer over to the client and was wondering how to load collections of parent and child entities.

You can see from the model that I am trying to load all the users and the relating UserRoles which are joined on the tblUsermmRole table.

When I run the the Linq query to crashed when loading the child entities as the query can not load a single instance into the collection.

Can I load these entities in a single query or should I load the users into the collection then build the child AccessRoles iteratively?

**Model**

[image]

**Data Transfer Object**

```
Public Class User

    Public Property ID As Int32
    Public Property Username As String
    Public Property Password As String
    Public Property AccessRoles As IList(Of UserRoles)

End Class

Public Class UserRoles
    Public Property Role As ApplicationRole
End Class

Public Class ApplicationRole

    Public Property ID As Int32
    Public Property Description As String

End Class
```

**Data Load**

```
Dim var = (From usr In ctx.tblUsers.OrderBy(Function(w) w.username)
              Join useraccess In ctx.tblUsermmRoles On usr.idUser Equals useraccess.idUser
              Join role In ctx.tblUserRoles On role.idRole Equals useraccess.idRole
                Select New User With {.ID = usr.idUser,
                                      .Username = usr.username,
                                      .Password = usr.pwd,
                                      .AccessRoles = New ApplicationRole With {.ID = role.idRole,
                                                                               .Description = role.description}}).ToList
```

**Exception Message**

```
{"Unable to cast the type 'Epms.Ui.Models.ApplicationRole' to type 'System.Collections.Generic.IList`1'. LINQ to Entities only supports casting EDM primitive or enumeration types."}
```

**Stack Trace**

```
   at System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.ValidateAndAdjustCastTypes(TypeUsage toType, TypeUsage fromType, Type toClrType, Type fromClrType)
   at System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.GetCastTargetType(TypeUsage fromType, Type toClrType, Type fromClrType, Boolean preserveCastForDateTime)
   at System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.CreateCastExpression(DbExpression source, Type toClrType, Type fromClrType)
   at System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.ConvertTranslator.TranslateUnary(ExpressionConverter parent, UnaryExpression unary, DbExpression operand)
   at System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.UnaryTranslator.TypedTranslate(ExpressionConverter parent, UnaryExpression linq)
   at System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.TypedTranslator`1.Translate(ExpressionConverter parent, Expression linq)
   at System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.TranslateExpression(Expression linq)
   at System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.MemberInitTranslator.TypedTranslate(ExpressionConverter parent, MemberInitExpression linq)
   at System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.TypedTranslator`1.Translate(ExpressionConverter parent, Expression linq)
   at System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.TranslateExpression(Expression linq)
   at System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.MethodCallTranslator.JoinTranslator.Translate(ExpressionConverter parent, MethodCallExpression call)
   at System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.MethodCallTranslator.SequenceMethodTranslator.Translate(ExpressionConverter parent, MethodCallExpression call, SequenceMethod sequenceMethod)
   at System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.MethodCallTranslator.TypedTranslate(ExpressionConverter parent, MethodCallExpression linq)
   at System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.TypedTranslator`1.Translate(ExpressionConverter parent, Expression linq)
   at System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.TranslateExpression(Expression linq)
   at System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.Convert()
   at System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ELinqQueryState.GetExecutionPlan(Nullable`1 forMergeOption)
   at System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.GetResults(Nullable`1 forMergeOption)
   at System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<T>.GetEnumerator()
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalQuery`1.GetEnumerator()
   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery`1.System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TResult>.GetEnumerator()
   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
   at Epms.Ui.DataProvider.DataAccess.EntityProvider.GetUsers() in C:\Users\phil.murray\Desktop\Data Provider\Epms.Ui.DataProvider\DataAccess\EntityProvider.vb:line 24
   at Epms.Ui.DataProvider.DataProvider.VB$StateMachine_0_GetUsers.MoveNext() in C:\Users\phil.murray\Desktop\Data Provider\Epms.Ui.DataProvider\DataProvider.vb:line 27
```

Comment: My VB isn't very good so this may be totally wrong syntax, but how about something like `.AccessRoles = New List(Of ApplicationRole) From { New ApplicationRole With {.ID = role.idRole, .Description = role.description}}`?

Comment: That gives me another exception -- Unable to cast the type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1' to type 'System.Collections.Generic.IList`1'. LINQ to Entities only supports casting EDM primitive or enumeration types.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I changed to UserRoles class to hold the ID int values

```
Public Class UserRoles
    Public Property Role As int32
End Class
```

Then loaded the data via the Linq query below.

```
Return (From usr In ctx.tblUsers.Include("tblUsermmRoles")
          Select New User With {.ID = usr.idUser,
                                .Username = usr.username,
                                .Password = usr.pwd,
                                .AccessRoles = usr.tblUsermmRoles.Select(Function(r) r.idRole)}).ToList
```

Comment: Your original approach was unnecessarily intrincate (and wasn't able to account for the "IList reality"). It is nice that you have posted a much proper code. In any case, this does not represent exactly an actual solution to your original question (why I am getting this error?). Not sure still why the solution I wrote (which did answer your original question) didn't work on your computer; but well... the important thing is that, at the end, things are done properly.